# Split column into two new columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 4 columns with value like this:

```
value_1
over 1 - 42 -> take this ; over 3 - 4
over 3 - 26 -> take this ; over 3 - 45 
over 5 - 25 -> take this ; over 2 - 80
```

And I need to make two column from each of them by splitting by ';'. 
And when I try this:

```
s = df['value_1'].apply(lambda x: x.split(';'))
df['value_left'] = s.apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['value_right'] = s.apply(lambda x: x[1])
```

Or this:

```
f['new_value1'] = df['value_1']
df['value_1_right'] = None
df['value_1_right'].update(df.new_band_bandw_1.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(';')[1] 
                      if len(x.str.split()) == 2 else None))
```

I got the same `error: List index out of range`. What is the problem, is it possible that the values are in some kind of list?

Any kind of solution is welcomed. Thanks

Comment: On which line do you get error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df[['value_left','value_right']] = df['value_1'].str.split(';', expand=True)
print (df)

                                  value_1                 value_left  \
0   over 1 - 42 -> take this ; over 3 - 4  over 1 - 42 -> take this    
1  over 3 - 26 -> take this ; over 3 - 45  over 3 - 26 -> take this    
2  over 5 - 25 -> take this ; over 2 - 80  over 5 - 25 -> take this    

    value_right  
0    over 3 - 4  
1   over 3 - 45  
2   over 2 - 80
```

Sample for multiple `;` - is possible specify which `;` is used for split:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value_1': ['a;r;e','b;r','c;g;t;e']
})
print (df)

   value_1
0    a;r;e
1      b;r
2  c;g;t;e

df[['value_left','value_right']] = df['value_1'].str.split(';', expand=True, n=1)
print (df)
   value_1 value_left value_right
0    a;r;e          a         r;e
1      b;r          b           r
2  c;g;t;e          c       g;t;e
```

Comment: It looks good, but I got this; ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Comment: It means there is multiple `;`, so `df['value_1'].str.split(';', expand=True, n=1)` should help

Comment: @jezrael what do you think about partition ?

Comment: @Dark - better here is `split`, but `partions` working too ;)

Comment: I know its not easy to beat the split answer, I just added another way ;)

Answer (score 2):

Another way with string `partition` i.e

```
df[['val1','val2']] = df[0].str.partition(';').iloc[:,0::2]

                                     0                       val1          val2
0    over 1 - 42 -> take this ; over 3 - 4  over 1 - 42 -> take this     over 3 - 4  
1   over 3 - 26 -> take this ; over 3 - 45  over 3 - 26 -> take this     over 3 - 45
2  over 5 - 25 -> take this ; over; 2 - 80  over 5 - 25 -> take this     over; 2 - 80
```